# Why is value passed as argument is not updated?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

My code doesn't return 10 !

It seems like `a` variable doesn't get updated !

Why ?

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
        { 
        Integer a = 5;
        sum(a); 
        System.out.println(a);
        }

    static Integer sum(Integer b)
        {
        b=b+5; 
        return b;
        }
```

Comment: Java is pass by value and it is not possible to pass Integer by reference in Java directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the value `sum(a)` to `a`. The function sum does not edit the value of the reference passed in parameter. You need to update `a`'s value by doing so `a = sum(a)`.

Comment: Benjamin Rio
but when we do with case of arrays
import java.util.Arrays;

class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int  arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        change(arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
    static void change(int nums[])
    {
        nums[1] = 69;
    }
}
Like this we don't need update arr[] again 
whats happening with Integers as wrapper objects please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it by reference.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
    Integer a = 5;
    sum(a); 
    System.out.println(a);
    }

static Integer sum(Integer &a)
    {
    a=a+5; 
    return a;
    }
```

now it will work.